# Can a unit-step function introduce non-linearity if used in the hidden nodes?

Tags: neural-networks, perceptron

I have a follow up from this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263768/can-a-perceptron-with-sigmoid-activation-function-perform-nonlinear-classificati). From the answers in that question, it's obvious that at minimum, a shallow network (only has a single hidden layer), as defined in the "Universal Approximation Theorem," is needed to have any sort of non-linearity. The original perceptron only had input and output nodes and used the unit-step function, hence it was simply a linear classifier.

If I have a shallow network and I use the unit-step function as the activation for the hidden nodes and the output nodes, is the model considered a non-linear classifier? I realize that this activation function is not desirable as it is not continuous/differentiable. But regardless of desirability, will this model be considered non-linear?

In fact, to take it a step further, if I had a shallow network and I used unit-step activation for the hidden nodes, but a linear activation for the output, this would still be considered a model that *can* (no guarantee that the training algorithm can train the model) solve non-linearly separable problems, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have a shallow network and I use the unit-step function as the activation for the hidden nodes and the output nodes, is the model considered a non-linear classifier?

Yes, such model could be used as a non-linear classifier.

> In fact, to take it a step further, if I had a shallow network and I used unit-step activation for the hidden nodes, but a linear activation for the output, this would still be considered a model that can (no guarantee that the training algorithm can train the model) solve non-linearly separable problems, is that correct?

Such model can (in theory) approximate any mapping to arbitrary precision (given enough units). From Bishop's great book *Neural networks for pattern recongition*, sec. 4.3.2, p. 131 (emphasis mine):

> Thus we see that  the  function   $y(x_1,x_2)$   can  be expressed  as  a  linear  combination  of  step  functions  whose  arguments  are  linear  combinations  of  $x_1$   and  $x_2$.  In  other  words  the  function  $y(x_1,x_2)$     can  be  approximated   by  a  two-layer  network  with  **threshold   hidden  units  and   linear   output  units**.